# lambda function to count the number of devices linked to a user

Tags: amazon-cognito

Please,
I would like to create a **post-authentication** Lambda hook, that makes call to the **AdminListDevices** API to count the number of devices currently linked to a user. Can someone give me an example on how to do that or point me to a link?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an official example for doing exactly this, but it's altogether possible.

If you wish to base the logic around trying to authenticate with a new device (i.e. only 5 devices can stream music for this account), Cognito included a newDeviceUsed boolean in the input your Lambda hook will get ([see docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html#cognito-user-pools-lambda-trigger-syntax-post-auth)).

On top of that, you'd need to have some credentials in your lambda hook with the authority to call admin list devices. Based on however your logic dictates (perhaps if newDeviceUsed is true), then, you'd call that API. It's worth noting that AdminListDevices will return both remembered and not remembered devices, so you might want to adjust your logic as needed.

Does that make sense?

EDIT:
More details on how Lambda handles credentials are available [in their docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-lambda.html). How exactly you want to call adminListDevices will vary quite a bit based on your logic and language of choice, but with the credentials having the power to do so, it should just be a normal call. See how SES is called in the Cognito [developer guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html#aws-lambda-triggers-post-authentication-example) examples.

Comment: Thanks for  your answer. Do you have a link or an example that explain how to do the second part of your answer?, call AdminListDevices within the lambda hook.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will exploit the links you provided to solve my problem.