# Aws Lambda Post-Authentication Trigger Function to limit simultaneous logins

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, mobile-development

New to this. Is there a way to limit simultaneous logins for cognito using Aws Lambda Post-Authentication trigger?

Basically I want my app to only have 1 user account logged in at a time, if at any point the user logs into the account via another (new device) the app either stops them, or logs them out of previous sessions.

What would a function for this look like?

Comment: see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59635482/aws-cognito-best-practice-to-handle-same-user-with-same-email-address-signing

Comment: @ChuckLaPress i dont think that thread helps. i looked it over  and it shows for PreSignUp lambda hook.

im looking for a hook for after login. user logs in one device A, then wihtout logging out, logs into Device B, (they should not be able to log into device B if Device A session is still active)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS Cognito User Pool without a password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45666794/aws-cognito-user-pool-without-a-password)

Comment: no it doesn't help. let me clarify.

I want to be able to use Post Authentication Lambda Trigger to figure out if a user is accessing their account from multiple devices and limit them from logging in on multiple devices. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-post-authentication.html)

One of the use cases that amazon mentions it says it can do this 
(https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/tracking-and-remembering-devices-using-amazon-cognito-your-user-pools/)

Comment: Something similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40516101/lambda-function-to-count-the-number-of-devices-linked-to-a-user